# I tried to send a python request to a proxy but it failed

Tags: python, python-requests, proxies

I tried to send a python request to a proxy but it failed. What did I do wrong?

Here's the code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://httpbin.org/ip'

proxies = {
    "http": 'http://103.250.153.242',
    "https": 'http://103.250.153.242'
}

response = requests.get(url,proxies=proxies)
print(response.json())
```

The result should have returned {'origin': '103.250.153.242'} but instead I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib
import requests

r = requests.get('http://google.com', proxies=urllib.request.getproxies())
```

But if you have proxies list:

```
from urllib3 import ProxyManager, make_headers

default_headers = make_headers(proxy_basic_auth='myusername:mypassword')
http = ProxyManager("https://myproxy.com:8080/", headers=default_headers)

# Now you can use `http` as you would a normal PoolManager
r = http.request('GET', 'https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Or:

```
import requests
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://proxy.server:port',
    'https': 'http://proxyserver:port',
}
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = proxies
r = s.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json').json()
```

Comment: Using the second approach (with requests), where do you enter proxy authorization credentials?

Answer (score 0):

You have these proxies:

```
proxies = {
  "http": 'http://103.250.153.242',
  "https": 'http://103.250.153.242'
}
```

But it's not correct because the IP has no port number, just add the port you have for this ip, no other port.
It will be something like this:

```
proxies = {
  "http": 'http://103.250.153.242:PORT',
  "https": 'http://103.250.153.242:PORT'
}
```